# Capacitors discharging into Coil

Tags: capacitor, oscilloscope, coil, tesla-coil

I have 2 capacitors  charging in parallel and then switching them in series to discharge into a wound coil of known inductance. My capacitors are 4nF 2000V and the charging voltage is 1000V. So at the moment they are switched in series they act as a 2000V 2nF capacitor. They discharge into a coil connected in parallel. The resistance of the coil is 2 Ohms the capacitors' ESR is 1 Ohm and an extra 100 Ohm resistor is added in series with the coil.
- I expect a voltage drop of (4 Ohms)*(10A)= 40V . As a result I expect I=V/R=950/104=9.1 Amps as a pulse on the coil. However all i end up with is a massive 700 Volt load drop. 
I think it has to do with the oscilloscope draining the capacitors while I detach the charging source and switch them in series. Switching them in series is done with triacs after I detach the charging source. 
Is my thinking right or have I not done something else correctly?

Comment: This should be simple enough to simulate in a spice with all possible parasitics added

Comment: What is the inductance of your coil?

Comment: Add a schematic to avoid wasting time trying to understand your words.

Comment: It seems that you expect the current to jump immediately to the V/R value, but that is not how a coil behaves.

Comment: @Marla The indutance is 5mH.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I understand that the coil would "resist" the current change. Could you explain further?

Comment: I suggest that you follow PlasmaHH's advice: put your circuit in a simulator so you can see what will happen.